# Allow a user to make a port forwarding, but nothing else via SSH

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have created a linux user and changed his default shell to `/bin/true`. I want to allow this user to set up a port forwarding via SSH, but not execute anything on the server.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi zxsimba, welcome here! you find *a lot* of things you find when you search for `restrict ssh` in the search box here. What have you found, which documentation have you read, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Or, to put @roaima's surprise in other words: what *do* you want the user to be able to do, then? As is, that SSH server would sound pretty useless for the user, and the logical consequence would be not letting the user log in at all.

Comment: he can use ssh protocol for tcp forwarding

Comment: You've written an excellent decoy for what you actually wanted to ask, then. This isn't about command execution at all – you don't care that they can execute `/bin/true` – you want to restrict a user to only open port forwardings. I'm fixing your question to reflect that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict an SSH user to only allow SSH-tunneling?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14312/how-to-restrict-an-ssh-user-to-only-allow-ssh-tunneling)

Comment: Or this? [How to add new Linux user restricted to ssh tunneling with password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/640088/100397)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the user's shell to `/bin/true`, you already prevented the user from executing anything on the server. The problem is, if the user connects "normally" to the server via `ssh`, after entering the password he/she is immediately disconnected, so it's not possible to use the port forwarding as well.

Your user should use `-N` parameter to `ssh`, like this:

```
ssh -N -L 8000:localhost:80 youruser@yourserver
```

This creates a port forwarding from the port 8000 of the machine the user is connecting from to the port 80 on server. The `-N` parameter tells `ssh` to only establish the connection, but to **not** execute the user's default shell (`/bin/true` in your case). So the user stays connected and the connection will "hang" until interrupted by Ctrl-C. During this time the ports are forwarded.

You can also make `ssh` to go to background before "hanging" (so the terminal is not blocked) by adding `-f` before `-N`. In this case, to quit the port forwarding later, you have to find the `ssh` process in the process list and kill it.

Comment: That does not *prevent* the user from executing anything. That's just a way for the *user themselves* to not execute anything *if they choose so*. That's not the point of the question.

Comment: @Fritz If the shell is `/bin/true` (as stated in the question), they can't execute anything anyway. The problem is, however, that if they connect with `ssh` "normally", without `-N`, they are immediately disconnected, so they can't use port forwarding (which OP wants). The `-N` is the way for them to stay connected, so they can actually use port forwarding.

Comment: "_By setting the user's shell to /bin/true, you already prevented the user from executing anything on the server_" - probably true, yes. However, it's still possible to wander around the file system using `sftp`, reading (and potentially writing) files. Other service applications may also accept the username/password credentials as sufficient authentication without referencing the shell defined in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @roaima If `/bin/true` is not in `/etc/shells`, then using sftp is not possible. Just tested it on my server. May be configuration dependent, but with standard configuration it works like that.

Comment: @raj I also tested. It's not in `/etc/shells` here either, but with `internal-sftp` set for `sshd` I can definitely log in

Comment: @roaima forcing `internal-sftp` is not a default setting, someone must have knowingly set that.

Comment: @raj oh absolutely. But seeing as the new default is no sftp subsystem at all it seems reasonable enough to assume someone might have set it to internal-server